# Why is my C++ object causing segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault

So I am developing a 3D game engine/api with C++. But I have come across an error I've never actually gotten before. The segmentation fault, now with some research I was able to understand what this was (or at least I thought I did, perhaps I don't understand it and that is why I continue to have an error). Anyways, when I try to use my pointer object, it crashes with that error:

```
void RenderEngine::Render(GameObject* object)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    std::cout << "debug 1\n"; //this prints
    object->RenderAll(m_defaultShader, this); //segmentation fault occurs here
    std::cout << "debug 2\n"; //this does not get printed
...more code...
}
```

I reference that function/method with this:

```
void Game::Render(RenderEngine* renderEngine)
{
    renderEngine->Render(&m_root);  //m_root is declared as 'GameObject m_root;'
}
```

And I have checked if m_root was null, it is not!
Also this is my first time using StackOverflow, so if formatting or anything is weird I apologize.

If anyone can help me understand why what I am doing is not working, that would be life saving.  If it by any chance have anything to do with my OS or compiler, I am on Linux Mint using Code::Blocks with the GNU GCC Compiler.

EDIT:

So upon further debugging and more slapping my head for being a dummy, I realized I hadn't initialized my game properly, so I added that function call, now that is where the crash happens:

Engine constructor:

```
Engine::Engine(int width, int height, double framerate, Game* game) :
    m_running(false),
    m_width(width),
    m_height(height),
    m_frameTime(1.0 / framerate),
    m_game(game),
    m_renderEngine(NULL)
{
    m_game->SetEngine(this);
}
```

m_game->Init() being called in the loop:

```
...code
        printf("%s\n", "sef"); //prints
        m_game->Init();   //segmentation fault crash
        printf("%s\n", "s324"); //does not print
...code
```

main function:

```
int main()
{
    Test game;
    Engine engine(800, 600, 60, &game);
    engine.CreateWindow("Boss3D Engine");
    engine.Start();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Start and CreateWindow functions:

```
void Engine::Start()
{
    if(m_running) return;
    Run(); // this contains the game loop of the engine, the first lines set m_running to true, then try to call the m_game->Init like above, so it doesn't even complete one iteration
}

void Engine::CreateWindow(const std::string& title)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE,32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE,16);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,1);

    SDLCreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, false);

    GLenum res = glewInit();
    if(res != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
    }

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_CLAMP);

}
```

SDLCreateWindow:

```
void SDLCreateWindow(const char* title, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{
    int mode = 0;

    if(fullscreen)
        mode = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | mode);
    glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    //SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC, "1");
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
}
```

I used the valgrind tool and I put the result in a text file, however it is so long that I cannot paste anywhere and I have never used valgrind before so I'm unsure how to interpret the results, here is the file: [valgrind file](https://www.mediafire.com/?06dzfkq4q9d1515)

After a few more hours of placing many many prints I have found that this is where it truly crashes now:

```
inline void AddLight(BaseLight* light)
{
    std::cout << "adding a light\n";
    std::cout << light << std::endl;
    //crash right below this line
    std::cout << "m_lights size: " << m_lights.size() << std::endl; //not printed
    m_lights.push_back(light);
    std::cout << "New m_lights size: " << m_lights.size() << std::endl;
}
```

This function crashes on first attempt to use it, m_lights is declared as:         `std::vector<BaseLight*> m_lights;`

Comment: For future reference, please don't tag your C++ questions as C. (also, welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Comment: Does it segfault when you just do `*object`? Have you inspected `object` with your debugger to make sure it's not just garbage?

Comment: @Cornstalks , am I not already using *object? Or perhaps I misunderstand you?  And apologies, I am still somewhat new to Code::Blocks, I used to be a windows developer with VS. How do I inspect it with the debugger?

Comment: Make sure all variables have their intended values. Use a debugger to check that. If you have a crash at the line you indicate, either `this` or `object` must be invalid pointers.

Comment: What's the type of `m_root`? How is its value initialized/set?

Comment: @RSahu it is a GameObject, its declared as I stated in that comment line

Comment: @BossLetsPlays, I see. Then, the only thing that I can think of is that it is not initialized properly, or something else has corrupted the object by overstepping memory.

Comment: It could be that `renderEngine` is null or invalid since the problem occurs on a line which seems to be the first access one of its members.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish yes it was, I was a dummy and forgot to call a vital function. However now the problem is occurring much earlier, if you look at my edit to the post

Comment: Still too little code. Where is the loop with that `m_game->Init`? Does it fail on first iteration or later? Run your program under `valgrind` to find any possible memory leaks and overrides. If you want further help show engine start and create window member functions.

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk I have just added more code as well as valgrind results to the post, and it fails before iteration can start, perhaps I should have been more clear. void Run() { INIT ... loop starts }

Comment: In main: `Test game;` In constructor: `Game * game`. Different classes. May this be a problem?

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk no Test inherits Game

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk if you look at the last bit of code in the post, my debug has led me to believe there is a problem with that vector, however I see no problem with it

Comment: @BossLetsPlays and what's exact crash message?

Comment: @BossLetsPlays It looks like you are trying to use object that's not allocated properly. Run your code under `gdb` or `cgdb` and try to find issue this way. I am no help without access to whole stack of code between crash and beginning of `main`. Basically try accessing any other member of object you got this vector in - if I am right you also *may* get garbage values/crashes when accessing other methods.

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk the crash simply says Segmentation fault. There are some valgrind stuff as well (DL link for the txt file with the results is in post)

Comment: @LukaszDaniluk I have actually solved the issue now, for whatever reason all I needed to do was change the terminal command used to compile the code...odd

Comment: @BossLetsPlays Do not add an answer/solution to your question body. Make an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for future reference:** Why this had affected it I'm not too sure, however I solved the issue by several hours of debugging and changing the terminal command used to compile the code, I now use `gnome-terminal --disable-factory -t $TITLE -x`